# Detecting lines formed by multiple blobs

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, hough-transform

After I threshold my original images, I get something like
[image]
and
[image]

The red circled parts are the aligned blobs that I want to detect (since these are from the noisy background and I want to get rid of them), so I can then create a mask for inpaint in opencv and get rid of these strong noise.

Right now I only have a way to detect the aligned blobs from first image.
So I connect and dilate and erode and did hough detection.

```
kernel = np.ones((1,10), np.uint8)
c_im = cv2.morphologyEx(invthresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)
d_im = cv2.dilate(c_im, kernel, iterations=2)
c2_im = cv2.morphologyEx(d_im, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)
e_im = cv2.erode(c2_im, kernel, iterations=2)

image_l = e_im
#line detection
rho = 1  
theta = np.pi / 180  
threshold = 15  
min_line_length = 150  
max_line_gap = 30  
line_image = np.copy(image_l) * 0  

# Run Hough
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image_l, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),
                    min_line_length, max_line_gap)
points = []
for line in lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        points.append(((x1 + 0.0, y1 + 0.0), (x2 + 0.0, y2 + 0.0)))
        cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 5)

lines_edges = cv2.addWeighted(image_l, 0.8, line_image, 1, 0)
ret2, lines_mask = cv2.threshold(lines_edges,254,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('lines_mask',lines_mask)
```

And here are the result images
[image]
and
[image]
In my case I can then use this as Mask_1 and multiply it with another threshold matrix from original grayscale image (get the darker pixels).

But there are several problems with my approach.

1. Sometimes the blobs aren't dense enough for me to do dilate and erode (like bottom image). What is a more versatile way to get the result I want?
2. (*If there isn't a good enough solution for Q1*, then I *at least* want to detect the bottom 2 circled lines in image 1 which crosses the boundary, like not in the middle of nowhere but touches the boundary of image) What is a good way to check if a line crossed the boundary? (Like in result 2, I don't want the part I crossed out. And a way to differentiate these mis-detected parts is whether they touch the boundary on both ends)
3. If I want to detect the blue circled parts in my images (because I want to eliminate them from my mask), what is a good way to perform it? The shapes are bigger then those blobs.

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks a lot!